# After precompiling assets for production, I get "File to import not found or unreadable: fonts." error in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, zurb-foundation

I have a Rails 4 app with a fonts directory in the assets folder, along with the usual stuff. I precompiled my assets for production, but now when I try to work locally I get:

```
Sass::SyntaxError
File to import not found or unreadable: fonts.
```

The whole error looks like this:

[image]

Haven't had much luck finding an answer. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I tried moving my assets into the assets block in the gemfile but that did nothing. Before that they weren't in any block, didn't work there either.

**application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Atbp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `config/application.rb`, look at your `config.assets.paths` line. It should include 'fonts'.

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

### Edit

After that, your fonts should be available with the `font-path` helper:

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'FontName'
  src: url(font-path('font-name.eot'))
  ...
```

Comment: I get the same error. I'll add my application.rb to my original post.

Comment: Just to make sure…you restarted your server after you edited that config file, right?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was trying to `@import "fonts"`, which is a directory and not a file. So as @nickcoxdotme suggested, I added

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

to `application.rb`

In addition, I was calling my fonts in the scss file like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'hamilton19';
  src: asset_url('hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.eot');
  src: asset_url('hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    asset_url(hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    asset_url('hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    asset_url('hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.svg#MonoSocialIconsFont') format('svg');
  src: asset_url('hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

When I needed to be calling them with `font_url` and `'/assets/` in the path.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'hamilton19';
  src: font_url('/assets/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.eot');
  src: font_url('/assets/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     font_url('/assets/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     font_url('/assets/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     font_url('/assets/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.svg#MonoSocialIconsFont') format('svg');
  src: font_url('/assets/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-719-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: You're going to love this: you can just use the `font-path` helper to get rid of all those nasty paths. See my edit.